# newDialogFragment() in an anonymous class returns error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been trying to figure this out but I haven't been able to.
I've been following a book,

```
Android 6 for Programmers_ An App-Driven Approach (3rd ed.)
```

I've followed each and every step but still it's returning an error.
This chapter is about making an app, "FlagQuiz App".
Also, the app works fine but crashes when the AlertDialog needs to be displayed.
The MainActivityFragment.java has the following code and where `new DialogFragment()` is defined, it gives a red underline error:

```
"Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static".
```

Actually, the method is an anonymous method for `OnClickListener`.
Here's the code that's returning this error.

```
// called when a guess Button is touched
    private OnClickListener guessButtonListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button guessButton = ((Button) v);//The method receives the clicked Button as parameter v
            String guess = guessButton.getText().toString();
            String answer = getCountryName(correctAnswer);
            ++totalGuesses;// increment number of guesses the user has made

            if (guess.equals(answer)){ // if the guess is correct
                ++correctAnswers;

                // display correct answer in green text
                answerTextView.setText(answer + "!");
                answerTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.correct_answer, getContext().getTheme()));

                disableButtons(); // disable all guess Buttons

                // if the user has correctly identified FLAGS_IN_QUIZ flags
                if (correctAnswers == FLAGS_IN_QUIZ) {
                    // DialogFragment to display quiz stats and start new quiz
                    DialogFragment quizResults = new DialogFragment() {
                                // create an AlertDialog and return it
                                @Override
                                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());//AlertDialog.Builder to configure and create an AlertDialog for showing the quiz results, then returns it.
                                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.results, totalGuesses, (1000 / (double) totalGuesses)));

                                    // "Reset Quiz" Button
                                    builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                                    resetQuiz();
                                                }
                                            }
                                    );

                                    return builder.create(); // return the AlertDialog
                                }
                            };

                    // use FragmentManager to display the DialogFragment
                    quizResults.setCancelable(false);
                    quizResults.show(getFragmentManager(), "quiz results");

                } else { // answer is correct but quiz is not over - load the next flag after a 2-second delay
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            animate(true);// animate the flag off the screen
                        }
                    }, 2000);// 2000 milliseconds for 2-second delay

                }
            }
```

My error log is:

```
FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process: com.ahsan.a47_dietel_flagquizapp, PID: 3089
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
```

Comment: pls post the crash log

Comment: FATALEXCEPTION:main
Process: com.ahsan.a47_dietel_flagquizapp, PID: 3089
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment null must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved. All you need to do is to is to delete DialogFragment anonymous class and outside onClickListener you define this static class:

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

   public MyDialogFragment(){} // end constructor

       // create an AlertDialog and return it
       @Override
       public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
           AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                   new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
           builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.results, totalGuesses, (1000 / (double) totalGuesses)));

           // "Reset Quiz" Button
           builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.reset_quiz, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       quizFragment().resetQuiz();
                   } // end onClick
               }
           );

           return builder.create(); // return the AlertDialog
       } // end onCreateDialog

   private MainActivityFragment quizFragment (){

       return (MainActivityFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.quizFragment);
   }}
```

Then you make an instance of MyDialogFragment in place where DialogFragment anonymous class was like this:

```
MyDialogFragment quizResults = new MyDialogFragment();
```

Everything will work well because I've tested it so many times.